# Spritekit physics failing to detect second adjacent item

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Kinda what the title says, I have a "wall" made out of multiple segments specifically for modular purposes. I have a contactTestBitmask that forces the player to stop moving in the direction of the wall once collided, but, if you slide along the wall to another segment, the player just rolls straight through it. I cannot do a collisionBitmask as the player runs fast enough to "phase" through the walls. I also cannot do collision as my camera and lighting are also dependent on the player's movement and position, and will not interfere with the walls (I think). If anyone could help point me in the right direction to allow me to make solid modular walls, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Increase the size (height or width of the module) to increase the size of the physics body and cause a little bit of overlap with the adjacent modules. As long as the physics bodies don't interact with each other (the wall physics bodies) you should be Ok. I was experiencing this on an SKTIleMap awhile ago, and that's how I managed to fix it. The overlap prevents the character from "slipping" through.

Comment: So what you're saying is is that the game isn't detecting the wall collision soon enough, and that providing overlap allows it to detect that collision on time?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is causing it. All I know is that there always appeared to be a "crack" in the wall until I increased my physics body size to accommodate  for it

Comment: I went ahead and added what I could to make the walls overlap, and I still get to phase through the "crack", overlap is about 10 pixels and the player is 13 pixels wide at the widest... I have no idea what's causing this, but it SUCKS

Comment: Another route you could take is building an algorithm that creates a single (or several) larger physics body that is generated from the combined surface area of all your wall objects.

Comment: might be what I have to do... thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the source of my problem, contact IS happening, I just have wonky flags and the system doesn't like that. I need a contact currently happening method, I guess